# Making personally defined cite commands clickable

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I have defined two cite-commands for my document:

```
\newcommand{\mcite}[1]{\textcolor{black}{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}}
\newcommand{\hcite}[1]{(\textcolor{black}{\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1}})}
```

Citing Author (Date) and (Author Date).

However, I would like these cite-commands to make clickable citations in the document (will not work with `hyperref` like `\cite`). Suggestions?

Comment: I guess this is the same issue you raised at the end of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488958/35864? So you are using `biblatex`, right? What exactly do `\mcite` and `\hcite` do? What is wrong with the usual `\textcite` and `\parencite`? One obvious difference is the `\textcolor{black}`, why do you need that?

Comment: Just to copy my comment about `\mcite` and `\hcite` from the other question: *Combining `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` as done in `\mcite` and `\hcite` is usually ill-advised, since commands defined like this will have problems with multiple citations, don't properly support pre- and postnotes and can at worst mess up citation tracking features. The proper way to define new `\...cite` macros is most of the time via `\DeclareCiteCommand`.* In this case, though, I would suspect there might be an even easier solution. But I'd need to know what the commands are supposed to do exactly.

Comment: The purpose of the new cite commands was to have to simple cite-commands for simple citing throughout the document. This way, not having to write "Author name et. al" before a \citeyear etc.

Comment: What's wrong with `\textcite` and `\parencite`?

Comment: Previously I had a problem using them, however it seems to have solved without me knowing why.. (sorry I'm a relatively basic user..) Thanks!

Comment: Retagged because https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488958/35864 confirms the OP is using `biblatex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is a bad idea to try and combine several of `biblatex`'s `\...cite` commands into a single `\newcommand`. Commands defined like this often need extensive workarounds to properly handle pre- and postnotes (i.e. `\cite[123]{sigfridsson}`, `\cite[Cf.][]{sigfridsson}` and `\cite[Cf.][223]{sigfridsson}`). Furthermore, they usually have extreme problems when dealing with citations to multiple works (`\cite{sigfridsson,worman}`). Last but not least, citation commands defined like this can cause `biblatex`'s citation tracker to get confused (this is mostly a theoretical worry, but I guess with enough ingenuity one could create an example where this is problematic).

New `biblatex` `\...cite` commands should <s>always</s> in almost all cases be defined via `\DeclareCiteCommand`.

In your case there is no need for that, however, since `\mcite` is essentially `\textcite` and `\hcite` is more or less `\parencite` assuming you use an author-year citation style.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}

\textcite{sigfridsson}

\parencite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998//Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998)//(Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998)]