# Biblatex references: Display names correctly and always displaying names

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, citing, overleaf

I want to display names in a Hardvard style used in my institution where references are displayed like:

Author, F. M., Author2 F. M., Author3 F. M. (2019) etc

However, my document shows it like this:

[image: my document it shows like this]

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
sorting=nyt,
citestyle=authoryear,
sortcites=true,
giveninits=true,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=99,
uniquename=init
]{biblatex}
```

Above is my `\biblatex` code. Does anyone have a suggestion where I've gone wrong?

Also I want all listings to include the author, not like the way it is displayed in the image below:

[image]

Edit:

Also I have defined two `\cite`-commands for my document:

`\newcommand{\mcite}[1]{\textcolor{black}{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}}
\newcommand{\hcite}[1]{(\textcolor{black}{\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1}})}`

Citing Author (Date) and (Author Date).

However, I would like these cite-commands to make clickable citations in the document (will not work with `hyperref` like `\cite`). Suggestions?

EDIT 2:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


%colors
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{30,75,180} %Blue
\definecolor{mycolor2}{RGB}{40,75,90} %Greyblue


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=authoryear, 
  maxcitenames=2,
  maxbibnames=99,
  giveninits=true,
  uniquename=init,
  dashed=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = black,
            urlcolor  = mycolor,
            citecolor = black,
            anchorcolor = mycolor]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\mcite}[1]{\textcolor{black}{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}}
\newcommand{\hcite}[1]{(\textcolor{black}{\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1}})}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Text written by 

"Cite": \cite{RN1} 

"Citeyear": \citeyear{RN1} 

"Citeauthor": \citeauthor{RN1} 

"Mcite": \mcite{RN1} 

"Hicte": \hcite{RN1}


% Bibliography
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}%
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Above you can see an example code of the one with the suggested solution, however I now get two errors:

"Undefined control sequence" for the:

```
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
```

and
"Latex error: Missing \begin{document}"

Comment: Can you please add a full example document that reproduces the output you get, a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 or MWEB: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864. That makes it much easier to help you. You may also want to consider splitting your question up into several smaller ones. Ideally a question on this site is really only about one issue and not about several related issues.

Comment: What I can say already is that combining `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` as done in `\mcite` and `\hcite` is usually ill-advised, since commands defined like this will have problems with multiple citations, don't properly support pre- and postnotes and can at worst mess up citation tracking features. The proper way to define new `\...cite` macros is most of the time via `\DeclareCiteCommand`.

Comment: If you get an error on `\DeclareDelimAlias`, your version of `biblatex` is outdated. (It must be more than a year old now. `\DeclareDelimAlias` was added in version 3.8 released on 2017-11-04.)

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using Overleaf. How do I update my biblatex?

Comment: Ugh, Overleaf... You can't really update `biblatex` there and are stuck with their outdated version. I'll update the answer with a workaround shortly.

Comment: See the edit at the end of the question for older versions of `biblatex` (such as the one run by Overleaf.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving aside the issue of `\mcite` and `\hcite`, which you asked about in [Making personally defined cite commands clickable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488723/35864) as well, we only need a few little changes.

For the name format you'll need

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
```

to get "Author, F. M.". See for example [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864) or [biblatex-dw first name first in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146137/35864).

You can get rid of the "and" with

```
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
```

And you can repeat author names instead of dashes with the option

```
dashed=false,
```

see [Get full name twice in Bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49140/35864).

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=authoryear, 
  maxcitenames=2,
  maxbibnames=99,
  giveninits=true,
  uniquename=init,
  dashed=false,]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,companion,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

#### Before

[image: Goossens, M., F. Mittelbach and A. Samarin//Knuth, D. E.//—//Sigfridsson, E. and U. Ryde]

#### After

[image: Goossens, M., Mittelbach, F., Samarin, A.//Knuth, D. E.//Knuth, D. E.//Sigfridsson, E., Ryde, U.]

---

If you are using an outdated `biblatex` version that does not define `\DeclareDelimFormat` yet, replace `\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}` with

```
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
```

Comment: I've edited my post with some new info.